# Converting integer (represented as a string) to a binary number in java

Tags: java, binary

Consider the following function in java

```
public static String changeToBinary(int n) {
    String s = "";
    
    while (n>0) {
        if (n%2==0)
            s="0"+s;
        else
            s="1"+s;
        
        System.out.println(s);
        n=n/2;

    }
    return s;
}
```

Which accepts an integer and converts it to a binary number (represented as a string).

I want to do the same thing, but to allow also numbers which would be bigger than the maximum integer of java. For that purpose I should use Strings instead of integers as the argument of my function.

How can I write the same function, but allowing strings that would represent numbers that may be bigger then the maximum integer value of java?

For example, if the input would be  `changeToBinary("45")` I expect the output to be `101101`

and if the input would be `changeToBinary("6147483647")` (That is a bigger number than java's maximal value for an integer), then the output would be `101101110011010110010011111111111`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could write routines to perform `%2` (easy) and `/2` (harder) on your decimal/strings.

Comment: Or you can use `BigInteger` (in interface or implementation). It supports values -2^Integer.MAX_VALUE (exclusive) to +2^Integer.MAX_VALUE (exclusive), which is a lot, and should be enough for almost all use cases

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways is to use `BigInteger`. Using BigInteger and `toString` method with `2` passed as parameter (as we want the string to be in binary form), we can easily get the binary representation of large numbers. The below method takes String as a parameter to support larger numbers.
Below is the implementation:

```
import java.util.*;

class Binary
{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        String decimal1 = "152246651651";
        String decimal2 = "62262262268823";
        System.out.println(extraLargeBinary(decimal1));
        System.out.println(extraLargeBinary(decimal2));
    }
    static String extraLargeBinary(String dec)
    {
        String bin = new java.math.BigInteger( dec ).toString( 2 );
        return bin;
    }
}
```

Output :
**10001101110010100110111000101100000011**
**1110001010000010010000000001101000001110010111**